# RAW CAN decoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, can-bus

I'm trying to import CAN data using a virtual CAN network and am getting strange results when I unpack my CAN packet of data. I'm using Python 3.3.7

Code: 
    import socket, sys, struct

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.PF_CAN, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.CAN_RAW)
interface = "vcan0"
try:
    sock.bind((interface,))
except OSError:
    sys.stderr.write("Could not bind to interface '%s'\n" % interface)


fmt = "<IB3x8s"

while True:
   can_pkt = sock.recv(16)
   can_id, length, data = struct.unpack(fmt, can_pkt)
   can_id &= socket.CAN_EFF_MASK
   data = data[:length]
   print(data, can_id , can_pkt)
```

So when I have a CAN packet looking like this.

```
candump vcan0: vcan0  0FF   [8]  77 9C 3C 21 A2 9A B9 66
output in Python: b'\xff\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00w\x9c<!\xa2\x9a\xb9f'
```

Where vcan0 is the interface, [x] is the number of bytes in the payload, the rest is an 8 byte hex payload.

Do I have the wrong formatting? Has PF_CAN been updated for newer Python version? Am I using CAN_RAW when I should be using CAN_BCM for my protocol family? Or am I just missing how to decode the unpacked data?

Any direction or answer would be much appreciated.

Also, here are some script outputs to can-utils values I've plucked. If I can't find anything, I'm probably just going to make collect a ton of data then decode for the bytes of data that don't translate over properly. I feel that i'm over complicating things, and possibly missing one key aspect.

```
Python3 output == can-utils/socketCAN (hex) 
M= == 4D 3D 
~3 == 7E 33
p == 70 
. == 2E 
@ == 40
r: == 0D 3A 
c == 63
5g == 35 67 
y == 79
a == 61 
) == 29
E == 45
M == 4D
C == 43
P> == 50 3E
SGN == 53 47 4E
8 == 38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than laboriously complete that table you started, just look at any ASCII code chart.  When you simply print a string, any characters that are actually ASCII text will print as that character: only unprintable characters get shown as hexadecimal escapes.  If you want *everything* in hex, you need to explicitly request that:

```
import binascii

print(binascii.hexlify(data))
```

for example.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I tried something similar, but must have not used the proper syntax. How would I have determined it was hex ascii? The semi translated output really threw me off. I thought it had something to do with formatting and padding or the protocol family I was calling? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've already run into the [python-can](https://github.com/hardbyte/python-can) library? If not we have a native python version of socketcan that correctly parse data out of CAN messages. Some of the source might help you out - or you might want to use it directly. `CAN_RAW` is probably what you want, if you plan on leaving virtual can for real hardware you might also want to [get the timestamp from the hardware](https://github.com/hardbyte/python-can/blob/develop/can/interfaces/socketcan/socketcan_native.py#L361).

Not all constants have been exposed in Python's socket module so there is also a ctypes version which made in easier to experiment with things like the socketcan broadcast manager. Docs for both are [here](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interfaces/socketcan.html).

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delayed response. I clicked that link Hardbyte, didn't have premission to access it. I'm currently looking into ESP32 and Beagel Bone Black as it's more compact for what I want to do.

Comment: Ah I think the doc link has moved - https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/interfaces/socketcan_ctypes.html

Comment: Also I used python-can on the Beagle Bone Black a few years ago. Great little board!

Comment: Thanks I came across that, will be playing around with it, I may actually pick up one of those TI CAN simulators to just learn more, really fun stuff! Thanks again for all your input, much appreciated kind sir!